# Converting list of objects to key value pair in java

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have java list of objects
`[["X","10"],["y","20"],["Z","30"]]`

How do I convert this to key value pair?
I want it to be

key:value
X:10
y:20
Z:30

Thanks

Comment: I have added answer, but probably this is duplicate - look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56502042/how-to-convert-a-list-with-key-value-pairs-to-dictionary

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your attempt and explain what problems you encountered.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to try to [solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'java.util.stream.Collectors' for this. Please refer to the below example

```
    public class KeyValue {

            private String key;
            private int value;

            public KeyValue (String key, int value) {
                this.key = key;
                this.value = value;
            }

            public String getKey() {
                return key;
            }

            public int getValue() {
                return value;
            }
    }
```

To convert List to Map

```
    List <KeyValue> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(new KeyValue("X", 10));
    list.add(new KeyValue("Y", 20));
    list.add(new KeyValue("Z", 30));


    Map<String, Integer> map = list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(kv -> kv.getKey(), kv -> kv.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

`dict( [["X","10"],["y","20"],["Z","30"]])`

Comment: I need it in java.

Comment: Sorry, you used Python syntax, so I thought you need Python sollution. Didn't read fully title - java word. You need to read this post https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example